# Cross platform job/task scheduler

Tags: linux, windows, task-scheduler

We have a mix of Linux, OSX and Windows servers that use crontab, Windows Task Scheduler, etc to run a bunch of bash/windows scripts, rsync commands, etc.

I would like to replace these OS specific schedulers with a centrally controlled system to get a getter overview, preferably something with a web console.

I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_job_scheduler_software) list of software on wikipedia which is, to put it mildly, overwhelming. I'm hoping someone could help me narrow it down a little, or suggest something else.

The requirements are as follows:

- Web based console for configuration, execution, etc
- Time based triggers similar to crontab or windows scheduler. Ideally also possible to select days in a calendar as we are a seasonal business which is open weekends only during spring/autumn, all week during summer in addition to Easter. Right now we have to manually adjust the windows task scheduler as the season progress.
- Can start scripts on remote machines for all major platforms (Linux, OSX, Windows)
- Possible to view logs from scripts on remote machines (some outputs to stdout, others to a specific logfile). Retain logfiles for all executions.
- Alerting mechanism if a job fails, preferably with some regex testing on the stdout as not all executable use exit codes as expected.

We only have 15-20 jobs all up, so nothing too fancy is necessary.

With many thanks,

Geir

Comment: This should not have been closed as off topic as he did describe the business problem he's trying to solve (cross platform scheduling), the research he's done (Wikipedia) and the steps he's already taken (cron etc). Sure would be nice if the orthodox SO members would let people post answers and let the community decide which answers are low quality by down voting them instead of suppressing discussion altogether.